# Test update method of Observer with EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, observer-pattern, easymock

I am  trying to test if the update method in a class which implements the Observer interface is called. I am using EasyMock to mock the ConcreteObserver so that I can verify that his update function is really executed.

This is my subject, the Observable class:

```
public class Subject extends java.util.Observable {

   public funcA() {
      ...
      notifyObservers(this,aVariable);
      ...
   }
}
```

I have the following class which is the Observer:

```
public class ConcreteObserver implements java.util.Observer {

   public ConcreteObserver(Subject subject) {
      subject.observer(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
   // TODO
   }
}
```

And this is my unit test:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateFunction() {
   Subject subj = new Subject();
   ConcreteObserver mockedObserver = EasyMock.
                                     createMockBuilder(ConcreteObserver.class).
                                     withConstructor(subj).
                                     addMockedMethod("update").
                                     createMock();

   mockedObserver.update((Observable) EasyMock.anyObject(),EasyMock.anyObject());
   EasyMock.replay(mockedObserver);

   subj.funcA();

   EasyMock.verify(mockedObserver);
}
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error :

> Expectation failure on verify: ConcreteObserver.update(, ): expected: 1, actual: 0

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Who calls the `update` of the Observer?

Comment: It is called when the notifyObservers() method is executed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test `ConcreteObserver` test it in isolation to your `Subject`; if you want to test `Subject` do it like this (which assumes an `import static` of `EasyMock`):

```
@Test
public void testUpdateFunction() 
{
  Subject subject = new Subject();

  Observer observer = createMock(Observer.class);
  observer.update(eq(subject), anyObject());
  replay(observer);   

  subject.observer(observer);
  subject.funcA();

  verify(observer);
}
```